# SuiteScript / JavaScript Array Indexing Issues

Tags: javascript, suitescript

I am working on dynamically generating XML for printing labels. I have an array of values generated with map, the format of this array should end up as such:

```
[[val1a, val1b, val1c],[val2a,val2b,val2c],[val3a,val3b,val3c]]
```

I am unable to log to the browser console in this application, so must use provided logging APIs to view the actual values of the array at any given point. The format presented by logging is as such:

```
val1a,val1b,val1c,val2a...
```

The values are generated like so:

```
for(var i = 0; i < lines; i++) { 
    for(var j = 0; j < quantity; j++){
        smCnts.push([i]);
    }
}
```

Where `i` is the line number of the specific "record", and j is iterating over the quantity, pushing the line number to the array `smCnts`. Resulting in a dataset like this (assuming line 1 has a quantity of 3, and line 2 has a quantity of 2 etc.):

```
[[1], [1], [1], [2], [2], [3]]
```

This array is then mapped using a function that gets values from the lines:

```
var smLbls = smCnts.map(getData);
```

Resulting in something like the first array listed in this question.

The problem results when trying to index the array for a specific value:

```
var foo = smLbls[1];
```

This returns nothing, I don't even know if it returns `null` as the logging api returns only: .

However, logging `smLbls` returns the first mentioned array as described in the second code snippet. What would be causing this issue? I need to be able to get the index of the index of an array like so:

```
var bar = smLbls[1][3];
```

Everything else is working as expected, I am just unable to access this data for whatever reason, maybe I am not understanding JavaScript fully?

Answer (score 0):

> I am unable to log to the browser console in this application, so must use provided logging APIs to view the actual values of the array at any given point. The format presented by logging is as such:

My advice, use the logs to extract a snapshot of your data:

```
nlapiLogExecution('debug', 'sample', JSON.stringify(data));
```

...and work in the browser.